# CDI doen't work in a simple Websphere Liberty Profile setup

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have Websphere Liberty Profile (wlp-beta-javaee7-2015.4.0.0.zip) installed on a local computer with the following server.xml file on server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
    <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.1</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
    <feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" />
  <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
  <application id="test2_ear_exploded" location="C:\myfolder\test2\out\artifacts\test2_ear_exploded" name="test2_ear_exploded" type="ear" />
</server>
```

The application is a trivial JSP page that calls a bean method. That method uses an @Inject-ed bean:

```
package pkg1;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Test {
    @Inject
    private Bean1 bean1;

    public String test() {
        return bean1.testMethod();
    }
}
```

After application startup I get NullPointerException there. It seems to me that CDI injection is not working.
Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: Have you tried adding an explicit beans.xml? It is possible that implicit BDA is not working in that beta.

Comment: Looks like it is not real piece of your application. How do you instantiate  object of the `Test` class?

Comment: @bkail Yes, I do have the beans.xml file in WEB-INF folder.

Comment: @Gas The point of using CDI is to **NOT** instantiate that object in the code. The CDI must do it instead of the code.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't show how you use/inject the Test class, that's why I'm asking. CDI will not inject, if it doesn't know that it should inject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **@Inject** in the JSP code which appears to be not working in JSPs.
When I moved all injection to Java and used **CDI BeanManager** to instantiate the first bean, all the other @Injects started to work.

Not very convenient, but proved CDI is working.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests Test is not a bean. If you want to perform injection on a class, the class should be either a Bean or JavaEE components detailed in Table EE.5-1 of EE7 specification.

Test class has no bean defining annotation, so it is not a bean in an implicit bean archive (no beans.xml or having a bean.xml but bean-discovery-mode="annotated").

To fix the problem, you can either annotate Test.java with a Bean Defining annotation such as Dependent, ApplicationScoped etc. Alternatively, add a blank beans.xml or beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="all", which effectively makes Test as a bean with Dependent scoped.

Comment: I have tried bean-discovery-mode="all" and also using Dependent, ApplicationScoped annotations - doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: How did you use the bean in the jsp? Did you annotate the bean with @Named? If it does not work, please share your .ear file?

Comment: thank you for your question. It helped me to find the problem!